# Generar una tabla de codigos a partir de Arbol de Huffman

Tags: algoritmos, haskell, teoría

dado un arbol del tipo:

```
data THuffman = Hoja Char | Nodo THuffman THuffman
```

y con el tipo de dato

```
type TablaCodigo = [(Char,String)]
```

Debo crear una funcion

```
extraerCodigos :: THuffman -> TablaCodigo
```

Que me genere una tabla de codigos a partir de un arbol de huffman. Hasta ahora tengo la parte recursiva de la funcion, pero no puedo lograr sacar como generar el codigo de strings.

El codigo seria: 1 si es un nodo de la derecha y 0 si es un nodo de la izquierda.
En la parte de Char en la tupla, iria el dato de la Hoja del arbol (que es un char)

Aca va lo que codee hasta el momento (la funcion principal funciona la helper no da resultado deseado)

```
extraerCodigos (Hoja x) = [(x,"0")]
extraerCodigos (Nodo (Hoja x) (Hoja y)) = [(x,enumC "0"),(y,enumC "1")]
extraerCodigos (Nodo (Hoja x) y) = (x,enumC "0") : (extraerCodigos y)
extraerCodigos (Nodo x (Hoja y)) = (y, enumC "1") : (extraerCodigos x)
extraerCodigos (Nodo x y) = (extraerCodigos x) ++ (extraerCodigos y)


enumC bin = if (tail bin) == "0" then bin ++ "0"
            else bin ++ "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes utilizar un argumento adicional para ir almacenando la cadena hasta llegar a un nodo hoja. Por lo tanto, la función `extraerCodigos` simplemente llama a la función auxiliar `extraerCodigos'` comenzando con una cadena vacía:

```
extraerCodigos :: THuffman -> TablaCodigo
extraerCodigos = extraerCodigos' ""
```

El caso base de `extraerCodigos'` es llegar a un nodo hoja, donde se devuelve el caracter contenido en la hoja junto al código acumulado. Si no es una hoja, se llama recursivamente a la función con el nodo izquierdo y derecho, añadiendo al código un `0` y un `1` respectivamente, y concatenando las listas resultantes.

```
extraerCodigos' :: String -> THuffman -> TablaCodigo
extraerCodigos' s (Hoja x) = [(x,s)]
extraerCodigos' s (Nodo l r) = extraerCodigos' (s++"0") l ++ extraerCodigos' (s++"1") r
```

De forma más eficiente, puedes ir añadiendo los nuevos dígitos del código como cabeza de la lista, y al final invertirla:

```
extraerCodigos' :: String -> THuffman -> TablaCodigo
extraerCodigos' s (Hoja x) = [(x,reverse s)]
extraerCodigos' s (Nodo l r) = extraerCodigos' ('0':s) l ++ extraerCodigos' ('1':s) r
```